# Put a flag when a user visit a topic : trouble

Tags: php, mysql, concurrency

Suppose I have a sort of forum with topics that users/admins can visit/manage.

When a user visit it, first I'll check if the topic exist; after I put a flag for say to the system if the user has been visited the topic.

This would be the basic code :

```
1        if((isset($_GET['trackid'])) && (ctype_digit($_GET['trackid']))) {
2            $query=mysql_query("SELECT date, user, zone, artist, event, data, res, complete, notes FROM topic WHERE trackid='".$_GET['trackid']."'",$mydb);    
3            if(mysql_num_rows($query)!=0) {
4                echo "Ok, The topic exist! Now I can say to the system that I have visited the topic"
5                
6                if (isset($_SESSION['nickname'])) $insert=mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO recent_adds (user, trackid) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['nickname']."','".$_GET['trackid']."')",$mydb);                 
7            }
8        }
```

Now, suppose that `User A` arrive to the line 4, and meanwhile an admin (`User B`) remove this topic (trought a special function for the admins, but this doesn't mean so much) : it will insert a inconsistent data to the database. (in fact that topic won't be exist anymore).

How the major forum/system that do this kind of operation get rid about this concurrency problem?

Comment: it is simple just track the topic view if it is set it means some one is viewing it so the delete should wait till the topic view is active in the session , cookie or database what ever your scenerio could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use FOREIGN KEYS to disallow inserting anything which have been deleted. Then you also get the benefit of doing a cascading delete.

Another solution is to run a batch job which cleans out inconsistent data. Along the lines of this solution, do not really delete the topic. Just mark it as deleted with a status flag and delete it later.

Comment: Uhm...looks as a nice solution that one with FOREIGN KEYS...! How it works? Justs put the FOREIGN KEYS?

Comment: Yes, it's not supported by MyISAM (but this has been in the manual for many years: "At a later stage, foreign key constraints will be implemented for MyISAM tables as well").

Comment: All my tables are on MyISAM, and my provider use only this! Argh... I think I must think to another way...

Comment: Then what about my second solution? Mark the topics as deleted, but remove them in a batch job later.

Comment: Yeah...but I hope to resolve with FOREIGN...is more professional :) Now I see if I can do somethings with my host provider ;) I'll let you know!